# How to check if a function parameter is constant?

Tags: c++, function, constants

This may be easy and I could be just missing what is right in front of me. However, I cannot figure out how to ensure a function parameter, passed by reference, can be modified. Essentially i need the following:

```
bool calculate(double lat, double lon, double dep, 
               double &x, double &y, double &z)
{
    if (x, y, AND z are NOT const)
    {
        perform the proper calculations
        assign x, y, and z their new values
        return true;
    }
    else //x, y, or z are const
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

The "if" statment check is really all i need

Again I apologize if this is already on this site or if it's a standard library function that i'm missing right in front of me. I come here all the time and virtually always get a good answer but I could not find anything on this already on here.

Comment: The variables won't be const if they aren't declared as such in the parameter list.

Comment: You can't pass a `const double` to a function that takes a `double&`. You don't need the check.

Comment: You might want to redesign that function to take three values, and return something like a vector. In the long run it will be much easier to reason about.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

if you have `double &x` then it isn't a constant. If you have `const double &x` then it is a constant.

In your case - no need to check, they aren't constants. The check is automatically performed in **compile** time.

See this:

```
void func(double &x){  X=3.14;  }

double d;
const double c_d;
func(d); // this is OK
func(1.54); // this will give an ERROR in compilation
func(c_d);  // this will also give an ERROR in compilation
```

You simply can't call a function that wants a (non `const`) reference with a constant.

This means that the compiler finds some bugs for you - like in your case, you don't have to return `true` or `false`, and you don't need to check it to try and find bugs - you simply compile and the compiler will find these bugs for you.

Comment: Of course, someone could use `const_cast` to lie to the function - but there's no way to detect that, so they'll just have to live with the consequences.

Comment: @MikeSeymour - true. BTW - can you even do a `const_cast` on a number such as 1.54?

Comment: No, you can only cast an *lvalue* (such as a variable) to an *lvalue* reference. A literal like `1.54` is an *rvalue*, so it won't work.